# change property of C# class type instance (e.g. dictionary) after it's defined

Tags: c#, oop, dictionary

I can set a dictionary to ignore case when comparing, during instantiation:

```
 Dictionary<string, long> SomeDict=new Dictionary<string, long>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

How do I set  StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase after the dictionary has already been instantiated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.

The best that you can do is create a new dictionary with a new comparer and copy all of the values over.

This is necessary for several reasons:

- Using the new comparer some of the keys may be considered equal, and will need to be merged
- New hashes will need to be computed for every existing key so that hashes created using the new comparer in the future will be able to find the old keys.

Answer (score 3):

By recreating it...

```
SomeDict = new Dictionary<string, long>(SomeDict, 
                                        StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

In the end the change you want is too much radical (all the hashes of the items would probably change. Only "probably" because if the keys are all in the form `"123"`, `"456"` the hashes would remain the same, but here we are speaking of the general case). The dictionary would have to be cleaned and refilled, so recreated nearly from scratch.

Comment: Is that the only way, or can this property be changed explicitly on the object without reinstantiation?

Comment: @LastTribunal Read the added text. No it can't.

Comment: @LastTribunal: I don't think it can be changed after the fact without recreating it.  The comparer is a read-only property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132092.aspx).  (I suppose you might be able to examine its internals with reflection and change it, but I advise against that.)  Besides, consider a scenario where the new comparison options invalidates the existing dictionary entries.  That would need to be checked, which happens when creating a dictionary.

Comment: @David you can easily work around the former by implementing your own comparer, which supports switching between different comparers internally. The big issue is your second point - the contract of the comparator is that comparing two elements will always yield the same result, now and in the future. Changing the way the comparison works breaks the contract and that is why what the OP wants is not possible without recreating the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with the other solutions that you have to recreate the dictionary, *but* if it would be easier to make it appear as if it's modifiable, you can create a class that hides the dictionary recreation:

```
public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dict;
    public IEqualityComparer<TKey> Comparer
    {
        get
        {
            return _dict.Comparer;
        }
        set
        {
            _dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(_dict, value);
        }
    }
    // constructors and IDictionary implementations, mirroring _dict
}
```